# Gradle Maven Authentification doesn't work with creds in gradle.properties

Tags: android, gradle, nexus

I'm currently trying to get a Gradle project to use the company internal nexus. 
After some searching I found the following to work:

```
repositories {
     maven {
            credentials {
                username= 'MyName'
                password= 'MyPass'
            }
            url 'https://company.com/repository/public/'
        }
    }
```

However I don't want to commit my creds so I put them into my `~/.gradle/.gradle.properties` as:

```
nexusUsername=MyName
nexusPassword=MyPass
```

And changed my `build.gradle` to:

```
repositories {
     maven {
            credentials {
                username= project.ext["nexusUsername"]
                password= project.ext["nexusPassword"]
            }
            url 'https://company.com/repository/public/'
        }
    }
```

At which point the server started responding with HTTP 401.
When I print them they still show up and look exactly the same.
Why does this happen and how can I fix this?